# ggsurvplot save output with correct dimensions

Tags: r

How can I save the output in jpeg format with a height of 2.2 Inch, Width 3.3 inch and resolution = 1000?

This is my current code

```
tar <- survfit(Surv(Y1$survialNew,Y1$p_censor) ~ 1 + 
Y1$Previous_Sternotomy + Y1$PGD_Grade1)
ggsurvplot(tar, data = Y1, xlab="Months Post Transplant", 
  ylab="Overall Survival", pval = TRUE)
```

Can someone suggest me the next lines of code? Or if we can just put everything in `ggsurvplot`?

Thanks,
Tariq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the output of `ggsurvplot` to a variable, then pass that to `ggsave`:

```
gg <- ggsurvplot( ... )
ggsave( "myplot.jpg", gg, width = 3.3, height = 2.2, dpi = 1000 )
```

Answer (score 7):

I met the same problem of creating a high-resolution plot using ggsurvplot. I'm not sure if Artem's code works because I tried it. I think `ggsave` should change a little

```
ggsave("myplot.jpg", plot = print(gg), width = 3.3, height = 2.2, dpi = 1000)
```

It's important to add `plot=print()`

Comment: As ggsurvplot produce a list object, you may sometimes need to precise that you want to save the plot part of the object :

ggsave("myplot.jpg", plot = print(gg$plot), width = 3.3, height = 2.2, dpi = 1000)